# Hosting Websocket Server on Openshift

Tags: openshift, wss, ws

I have a service currently forwarding `https://url...` to `http` port `8080` of the pod.

Now I want to also forward `wss://url:8443` to `ws` port `8443` of the pod.

I have a few questions, such as:

- Will openshift map wss to ws by default if I check the secure option?
- Do I need 2 services using 1 pod?
- Do I need 1 service with 2 routes?
- Is there openshift documentation specific to opening wss connection to websocket server?
- Is there an example that works with openshift done by someone else (with enough information to reproduce...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to us "wss://:443/route"

route is optional depending on how you define the socket server.

Port is optional but you can verify it by going to the url given by openshift so https://... and add :443, The page might load if you are using glassfish/grizzly, trying url:8443 or 8080 or 80 or 8000 etc you can figure which port you are meant to use, default for https is 443.

Comment: I had a similar issue of websocket failing to connect across containers on the same pod, on openshift. This answer helped me realize that it may work better through HTTPS, so I eventually created a route to my service and connected through this route. Feels kind of hacky, because one container goes through a route to access another container on the same pod, but at least is works.